# JavaScript(Canvas): How to update the pointer's position inside the animation frame and NOT inside the event listener?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, requestanimationframe, mouse-position

I was creating a JS script where a point follows the mouse pointer, by a given displacement PVector.
I implemented a self made PVector class, I tested it and it works well.

My question is: Is there any workaround to **update** the mouse **position inside** the `requestAnimationFrame(animate())`

For now I am updating my mouse position inside the event handler, and it is not working well:
 
`window.addEventListener('mousemove' e =>{ updateMousePosition() });`

I have searched about this and I couldn't find a solution or maybe I didn't understand it.

Comment: I don't know what your `updateMousePosition` function does, but what you probably want to do here is have the `mousemove` handler update in-scope mouse position variables that you then use in in your `requestAnimationFrame` handler.

Comment: Side note: `requestAnimationFrame(animate())` looks suspect. You pass a **function** to `requestAnimationFrame`. Unless your `animate` function *returns* a function you want called, you shouldn't be calling `animate` there. Instead: `requestAnimationFrame(animate)`. But again, it depends on what `animate` does/returns. If you're really using it to *create* and return a function, then your original is fine.

Comment: update `x` and `y` variables in the `event`, and draw the pointer according to the `x` and `y` vars in the `animation frame`

Comment: Note that mouse events  are now throttled by specs and Blink+Gecko to screen refresh rate, just like requestAnimationFrame. So if you have a problem with updating the values in the event handler from either Chrome or FF, then you'll probably face the same when moving it to the rAF callback.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, the animate() function is calling my methods for drawing. updateMousePosition() just assigns the x and y values to a PVector.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If i stop moving my mouse my mouse position variable it doesn't get updated, and keeps drawing a movement vector in the old mouse position.